# class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/social/SocialAutoConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, configuration, boot, auto

please solve the issues in spring boot related

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuHsi.png)

l am added new dependency. spring boot upgrade 1.5.10 to 2.1.10 version

class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/social/SocialAutoConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist.

Spring boot is very easy to use and it does a lot of things under the hood, you might not be aware of. In future, a good developer will be who will know exactly what is going on behind spring boot auto configuration, how to use it in your favor and how to disable certain sections which you do not want into your project.

Comment: You are using incompatible versions of components. Spring Social is a dead project and hasn't been supported for a while any more in Spring Boot. That being said don't add code, stacktrace etc. as images as thos are unreadable and in this case requires a click. Post them as code. Also you have an error but haven't added your dependencies to the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.